# Can a minor act as an officer or director of a corporation?

Tags: corporate-law, minor, massachusetts

I have two questions:

1. I was wondering if a minor could act as an officer of a corporation; **and**
2. if a minor can act as a director on a board of directors in the Commonwealth of Massachusetts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Most likely* **no**.

[Minors can't sign legally binding contracts unless there's an excetion](https://statelaws.findlaw.com/massachusetts-law/massachusetts-legal-ages-laws.html). They can't handle large business transactions. Both are jobs that fall upon both directors and officers of a corporation. A director or officer also might need to sue on behalf of a company, and minors can't do that either. As such, minors below 16 can't hold such positions, in fact, such a position is a job, [which requires a Work Permit](https://www.mass.gov/service-details/youth-employment-permit-information). And there are [child labor laws](https://www.mass.gov/service-details/massachusetts-laws-regulating-minors-work-hours), which for example dictate that there is to be no work for minors below 14.

The contracts a company needs to sign to do anything might not constitute necessities of the minor, which would be void, and other companies might not want to risk such and not want to contract with a company run by a minor.